# Populating data in a different table row from one array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have the below code regarding populating the data in different table row from one array.

I want to display data in a different row and get language dynamically in language column (like below picture)

[image]

Object:

```
{
  "English Name": "English",
  "English Description": "English Description",
  "Hindi Name": "Hindi Name",
  "Hindi Description": "Hindi Description",
  "Marathi Name": "Marathi Name",
  "Marathi Description": "Marathi Description"
}
```

```js
  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    var result = JSON.parse(response);

    var colName = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      for (var key in result.data[i]) {
        if (colName.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          colName.push(key);
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(colName);

    var showData = document.getElementById('showData');
    for (i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      var row = `<tr>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>${result.data[i].EnglishName}</td>
            <td>${result.data[i].EnglishDescription}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hindi</td>
            <td>${result.data[i].HindiName}</td>
            <td>${result.data[i].HindiDescription}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Marathi</td>
            <td>${result.data[i].MarathiName}</td>
            <td>${result.data[i].MarathiDescription}</td>
        </tr>`;
      showData.innerHTML += row;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to display JSON object data in different table row **(Like uploaded picture)**

Comment: Yes but what is your problem with what you've done so far?

Comment: in my code i'm manually add language name and `keyname` for particular row (td) but i don't know how to add different language in new row and also get language dynamically in first column

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your JSON needs to look more like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "language": "English",
      "familyName": "English Name",
      "familyDescription": "English Description"
    },
    {
      "language": "Hindi",
      "familyName": "Hindi Name",
      "familyDescription": "Hindi Description"
    },
    {
      "language": "Marathi",
      "familyName": "Marathi Name",
      "familyDescription": "Marathi Description"
    }
  ]
}
```

And in your loop, a row should look like this, if `result.data` contains the arrays:

```
var row = `<tr>
        <td>${result.data[i].language}</td>
        <td>${result.data[i].familyName}</td>
        <td>${result.data[i].familyDescription}</td>
    </tr>`;
```

**EDIT**

If the JSON always has the same format, then you can access it by key, no need for a loop:

```
        <td>English</td>
        <td>result.data["English Name"]</td>
        <td>result.data["English Description"]</td>
```

Comment: Yes, but i have to work with present JSON data format

Comment: can we make condition for new language in new row?